# For what values of $a$ and $b$ is this vector a linear combination of three others

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm asked to find out for what values of $a$ and $b$ is the vector $(-a,1,b)$ a linear combination of the set
$$(a,1,2a),(0,1,2a),(2a,-1,a+2)$$
I tried to solve it by expressing the linear combination in matrix form, but I'm not being able to reduce it and solve it.
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Please show how you "tried to solve it by expressing the linear combination in matrix form".  I'd put the vectors in rows and try to row reduce the resulting matrix.  There's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on using MathJax in Meta Math.SE, and I can help with details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the matrix$$M=\begin{bmatrix}a&0&2a\\1&1&-1\\2a&2a&a+2\end{bmatrix},$$whose columns are those three vectors. If its determinant is not $0$, then those vectors span $\Bbb R^3$, and therefore $(-a,1,b)$ is a linear combination of them. And $\det M=3a^2+2a$, which is $0$ if and only if $a=0$ or $a=-\frac23$. So, you only need to deal with these two cases.

If $a=0$, then your vectors are $(0,1,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(0,-1,2)$, and $(-a,1,b)$ is $(0,1,b)$. Clearly, it is a linear combination of the three vectors for any value of $b$:$$(0,1,b)=\left(1+\frac b2\right)(0,1,0)+\frac b2(0,-1,2).$$

Can you deal with the case $a=-\frac23$ now?

Comment: Thank you so much, that is precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @Arthur Indeed. And I provide an example at the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Right you are. I was apparently distracted and had things reversed in my head.